# Load and show a page from another domain without showing the orginal URL, using javascript

Tags: javascript, url, hide

I am trying to load a page from a domain (say abc.com) to my website (say xyz.com). I would like to show a page from abc.com within xyz.com without showing the original URL. This means the site visitor will not be able to find out the original source URL (abc.com).

Comment: If you fetch *the other site* at the client, the client will allways be able to get hold of the source. If that is absolutely forbidden, you'll have to fetch it on the server.

Comment: Dear Yoshi, Thanks for your time and support. Could u plz explain . How can I solve it ?

Comment: You'll have to use a server-side technology (e.g. php). Fetch the page contents that other side provides using the available methods of the technology chosen. And deliver the result to the client. This communication is not visible to the client, and thus he can not know your source. Though there are some pitfalls which have to be looked at (e.g. source of additional files like stylesheets, javascripts, images, ...).

Comment: But I would like to use show the page to my clients web sites. So the sites may have different different technologies(PHP/JSP/.net) . So it is not possible to use a server side script for that.. Is there any other solution ..../

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a page in your website and put an iframe in it and set the url of that iframe as url of the page of the other website, in this way the page will be loaded from other site and url will be of your site.

```
<iframe src="http://www.abc.com/thepage" style="border-width:0;width:100%; height:800px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Dear Imran, thanks for your valuable suggestion. But i am confused about ' set the url of that iframe as url of the page of the other website'. Could u plz show me an example .  Thanks in advance

Comment: Dear! You are welcome, with URL I mean set src of iframe as I have shown above in my answer.

Comment: Dear Imran, Thanks for your valuable time and support. But I would like to make a feel to the end user that the page is from my site . Not from the remote url. By using i frame, how can I do this? Now the iframe shows a border...

Comment: I have updated the iframe tag in my answer, when you set border-width:0 the iframe will not have any border, set the width and height of iframe to look like as part of your page.

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe src="http://www.xyz.com/thepage" width="300" height="300" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

Then you need to configure you server to act as reverse proxy to abc.com for the /thePage